# Is it possible to call a function one after the another in python?

Tags: python, oop

OOP noob here..
But.. is it possible to call a function after a function. I don't know how to describe it, so I'll ask it with an example:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.email = ''

    def set_email(self, email):
        self.email = email

    def print_email(self):
        print("You email is: {}".format(self.email))

    def with_name(self):
        print("Your name is {} and email is {}".format(self.name, self.email))

subject = Human("Bucky", 24)
subject.set_email("bucky@gmail.com")
subject.print_email().with_name()   # Doubt here
```

Is it possible to call a function after `.print_email()` such as `.with_name()` so that the email gets printed with name and the `print` function in the `.print_email()` function doesn't gets printed at all??

Saw this type of thing in Javascript, was thinking that is it possible here in python?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but the function needs to return something, that has the method you're calling on it.

Comment: That's called function / method chaining and is not related to the programming language. It only requires a programming language with OOP. Here is a tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-Python-class-method-chaining

Comment: Wait, why would you want to do that?  `print_email(with_name=True)` is better in Python.

Comment: btw, with the code you have posted you only need to call: `subject.with_name()`.

Comment: Sure, it's *possible*. You would need to design your classes appropriately: they would both need to have a `__str__` method (for converting to a string representation) and would need to return `self` in most of the methods.  The [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) module uses a calling convention something like that.

Comment: `Does this answer your question? Fluent interface with Python – quamrana`.Yes this does solves my problem. Only needed to return self. Thankyou very much.